# How to replace items in list with their indexes

Tags: python-3.x, list, indexing

So let say I have a list:

```
x = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

what I want to do is to swap items in list for their index number, like so:

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

How can it be done? I have tried using `.index`for lists, but It didn't work.

Comment: Please show what you actually tried, as opposed to a thumbnail description of it.

Comment: So you want a list of consecutive numbers? Whats the point? Use `range`.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the code :

```
x = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']  # create a list of strings

x = [x.index(item) + 1 for item in x]

print(x)  # print the new list of index numbers
```

Comment: This could simply be done by `list(range(1, len(x)+1))`, or even `[i for i, _ in enumerate(x, 1)]`. Why change a simple O(N) operation to O(N^2) by including a `.index` call in the loop?